# MLE negative log-likelihood truncated normal in R

Tags: r, rstudio, truncated, mle

I am a bit stuck with my code and i would greatly appreciate it if somebody could help me!

The code below is basically a function I've written that enables you to calculate the maximum likelihood estimates of μ and σ2 on the basis of an iid sample x1, …, xn from a truncated normal distribution with parameters μ,  σ2 and τ, where the value of τ is known.

This is the code i have up to now.

```
tnorm.negll <- function(theta,xbar,SS,n,tau){

  #storing variance into a more appropriate name
  sigmasq <- theta[2]
  logvar <- log(sigmasq)

  if (sigmasq<0) {
  warning("Input for variance is negative")
  return(Inf)
  }
  
  #storing mean into a more appropriate name
  mu <- theta[1]
  
  #standard normal
  phi <- function(x) exp(-x^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)

  #using the given formula for the negative log-likelihood
  negloglike <- (n/2)*(logvar) + (SS - 2*n*mu*xbar + n*mu^2)/(2*sigmasq) + n*log(1-phi((tau-mu)/(sqrt(sigmasq))))

  #returning value:
      return(negloglike)

}
```

I now need to write another function, say trnorm.MLE(), that will use the function above to calculate the maximum likelihood estimates of μ and σ2 given a vector of observations x1, …, xn and a value of τ.

I decided that my function should have the following arguments:

- x : vector of observations,
- tau : value for threshold,
- theta0 : vector with elements theta0[1] initial guess for mu and theta0[2] initial guess for sigmasq.

Ideally,  the trnorm.MLE() function should return a vector of length 2, where the first component is the MLE of μ and the second component is the MLE of σ2.

As a guess , I've written this:

```
x <- rep(1:11, c(17,48,68,71,42,19,14,7,1,0,1))
tau <- 3
theta0 <- c(3,15)

xbar <- mean(x)
SS <- sum(x^2)
n <- length(x)
nlm(tnorm.negll,theta0,xbar,SS,n,tau,hessian = TRUE)
```

I know this is far from correct but I cannot express it correctly!
I get various errors

> Error in nlm(tnorm.negll, theta0, xbar, SS, n, tau, hessian = TRUE) :
> invalid function value in 'nlm' optimizer

or

> Error in if (theta[2] >= 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Thank you for reading this. Hopefully somebody can guide me through this?

Best Regards.

### edit : changed how tnorm.negll returns its results

Comment: Did you read `?nlm`? What the doc says about `f`, the function to be minimized? What does your function return instead? Just to be clear: your function is very weird, since it return sometimes a `list` and some other times a `character`, while `nlm` requires `f` to return `a single numeric value`.

Comment: i changed tnorm.negll to return negloglike and 999999 if variance is negative. ill edit the post as well.

Comment: Use `Inf` instead of `999999`. Put `if (sigmasq<0) return(Inf)` at the second line: what's the purpose of making some calculations if you already know the result? Your function now works with your example.

Comment: thanks nicola for your comments! i changed 9999 to Inf as you suggested.

Comment: i get these errors though
Warning messages:
1: In log(sigmasq) : NaNs produced
2: In sqrt(sigmasq) : NaNs produced
3: In f(x, ...) : Input for variance is negative
4: In log(sigmasq) : NaNs produced
5: In sqrt(sigmasq) : NaNs produced
6: In f(x, ...) : Input for variance is negative
7: In log(sigmasq) : NaNs produced
8: In sqrt(sigmasq) : NaNs produced
9: In f(x, ...) : Input for variance is negative
Can i just ignore them? also the functions returns 
$estimate
[1] 3.503279 3.148362

that means 3.503279 is mu and 3.148362 is sigmasq?

Comment: You are not getting any errors. You are getting warnings, which are a very different thing. You can avoid some of them following my advice of returning `Inf` as soon as possible. For the meaning of the value returned by `nlm` I suggest you to read carefully the documentation (your intuition is correct BTW).

Comment: Nicola thank you very much. Turned my gloomy afternoon into a less gloomy one! :) i think i no longer get any warnings when run correctly. thank you again!